# RegEx validation for only empty space; should accept space between words/characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing reg ex for UI validation for following requirements:

1. It should contain alphabets and/or numbers.
2. It can contain "_"(the only acceptable Special character).
3. "white space" in between the characters can be acceptable.
4. No empty space (only white spaces are not allowed).

Here's my reg ex:

```
Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9? ,_-]+$')
```

Now except '#4', everything else is working fine. It's just accepting only white space; whereas as per requirement white space can be allowed only in between characters.

Comment: Can you have multiple consecutive whitespaces between "words"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex becomes heavier, but you can do this:

```
Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9?,_-](\s?[A-Za-z0-9?,_-]+)*$')
```

This ensures that:

- The first character is a valid character, and not a space
- The string either ends here, or

  - Contains any sequence of `[optional whitespace][at least one valid non-whitespace character]`

So that these match:

- "a a"
- "a"
- "aa"

And these don't:

- "" (not sure if you want this one to match)
- "a "
- " a"
- "a a a "

Note: I used your pattern, which allows `?`, `,` and `-` which are not included in your second requirement.